# Why is Human Intellect the only "faculty" with a dedicated Beracha in Amidah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, sefirot-attributes

Only [one of the berachot](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Edot_HaMizrach%2C_Weekday_Shacharit%2C_Amida.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in Amidah (notably, the first one after the 3 berachot of praise; אַתָּה חוֹנֵן לְאָדָם דַּֽעַת) thematically corresponds to a faculty in the human being, namely intelligence. There is no beracha **dedicated** for blessing us with any emotion, any character trait, for pertaining to our will or desire. Another way to put it, there is no beracha for any of the sefirot other than the intellectual sefirot.

Does anyone know of a specific explanation as to why this is?

Comment: See the prayer of the angels (Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer, 40), ברוך אתה ה' חונן הדעת G-d has given us the Daas to understand things in live according to His will.  The Yerushalmi in Brachos says Rebbi said: I wonder why they eliminated “Gracious Giver of knowledge” on Sabbath; if there is no knowledge, from where comes prayer? Rebbi Isaac said: Knowledge is great because it is in the middle between two mentions of divine names as it is said (1Samuel 2:3): “Certainly, a G-d of knowledge is the Eternal”.

Comment: What about והסר ממנו יגון ואנחה?

Comment: Why would you translate "da'as" as "intellect" rather than "awareness of Hashem"?

Comment: Although the explicit nature of the request validates your question, it might interest you to know that in the AriZal's siddur (the original one, before the Alter Rebbe's edits) , names of Hashem were vowelized intentionally in each bracha to request for Hashem to provide the response for the bracha *through the response type of a specific sefira*. (This explanation follows the Tzemach Tzedek in Shoresh mitzvos Hatfilah, quoting Don Yitzchak in response to the Rashba's question regarding why it is not idolatry to reference the Sefiros in davening. The Rashba accepts the answer vigorously. )

Comment: @Yehuda the prayer references all 3 intellectual faculties in the sefardi version, and 2 of them in the ashkenazi. I wasn't going into specifics

Comment: @RabbiKaii In both versions they are explicit Kabbalistic references.

Comment: If the person who downvoted this could explain why, I would benefit greatly.

Comment: I downvoted because your premise is false, as I explained in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [yaarot divash](https://www.sefaria.org/Yaarot_Devash_I.1.15) says that "intellect" is the main creation of a human. As he explains, our intellect is the means through which we can elevate ourselves from dirt "אדם" to רוחני.
Refer there for more of an understanding because I feel like I did his work a major injustice.

By the way, I highly recommend his pirush on shemoneh esrai which I linked.

Comment: Amazing answer thank you

Comment: @RabbiKaii. Not sure if I should edit this into my answer. But there are numerous meforshim who explain this gemara  [וְכׇל מִי שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ דֵּעָה — אָסוּר לְרַחֵם עָלָיו. anyone without knowledge, it is forbidden to have compassion upon him.](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.33a.19) as follows: Atah chonen is first in order for hashem to have mercy and answer your preceding requests in 18.